# R: Time Series graph of median concentration using tidyverse

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series, tidyverse

I'm very new to R and I'm trying to create a time-series plot for the median concentration of a given variable in my dataset.. however I'm not getting what I want and I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. Some of the data comes up as N/A once I create the new dataframe (data_median). This makes the graph incomplete.. I would greatly appreciate any help! Thanks in advance!

Preview of my code:

```
if (!require(pacman)) {
  install.packages('pacman')

}

pacman::p_load("ggplot2","tidyr","plyr","dplyr")
#### Read in the necessary data ######
roadsalt_data<-read.table("QADportaldata_1988-2015.tsv",header=T,sep="\t",fill=T,stringsAsFactors = F)
#Convert date column from a character class to a date class so ggplot can  display as a continuous variable ###
roadsalt_data$stdate <- as.Date(roadsalt_data$stdate)
## Filter dataset to only contain columns I need ########
filtered_param <- roadsalt_data %>% 
  select(orgid, stdate,locid, charnam,val) %>%
 filter(between(stdate, as.Date("1996-01-01"), as.Date("2015-07-01"))) %>%
  filter(charnam == "Chloride")

  filtered_param$val <- as.numeric(as.character(filtered_param$val))

  data_median<- 
  filtered_param %>% 
  mutate(year=as.Date(cut(stdate, breaks = "year"))) %>%
  group_by(year) %>%
  summarize(xmedian = median(val))

## theme for plots ####
graph_theme<- theme_linedraw()+
              theme(plot.title=element_text(size=15, face="bold",vjust=0.5,hjust = 0.5),
                    legend.text=element_text(size=10, face="bold"))


graph1<-ggplot(data_median, aes(year, xmedian)) +
  geom_line(color="blue") +  
  scale_x_date(date_labels = "%Y", date_breaks = "2 year") +
  ggtitle("Median Chloride Concentration (mg/L);1997-\n2015") +
  xlab("Date") + ylab("Median Chloride Concentration") +
  graph_theme
```

Preview of my dataset:

```
  A tibble: 16,209 x 5
   orgid   stdate     locid           charnam  val  
   <chr>   <date>     <chr>           <chr>    <chr>
 1 USGS-NJ 2014-11-20 USGS-01482500   Chloride 23.6 
 2 USGS-NJ 2015-06-24 USGS-0146453250 Chloride 221  
 3 USGS-NJ 2014-09-15 USGS-01392150   Chloride 144  
 4 USGS-NJ 2015-05-28 USGS-01411035   Chloride 10.8 
 5 USGS-NJ 2015-06-16 USGS-01411466   Chloride 10.5 
 6 USGS-NJ 2015-06-16 USGS-01411444   Chloride 5.76 
 7 USGS-NJ 2015-06-16 USGS-01463500   Chloride 27.5 
 8 USGS-NJ 2015-06-16 USGS-01407821   Chloride 37.1 
 9 USGS-NJ 2015-06-02 USGS-01464527   Chloride 22.5 
10 USGS-NJ 2015-06-02 USGS-01405340   Chloride 78.3
```

Graph that I want to create:
[image]

Graph I'm getting:
[image]

Comment: Check whether you have any `NA`s in the data from which you're calculating a median. `median` has a default `na.rm = F`, so if there's a missing value in a vector, you'll just get back `NA`. Try changing this to `na.rm = T`.

Comment: @camille how can I check if there any NAs in the entire dataset? I tried doing is.na(filtered_param$val) and it only shows me up to [987]

Comment: That sounds like you ran into the limit of how many rows RStudio will print to the console. `is.na` gives a true/false value for every element in a vector, so `sum(is.na(x))` will give you the total number of `NA`s in the vector `x`, and `which(is.na(x))` will give you the indices of any `NA`s in the vector

Comment: @camille nevermind! I put the argument in your comment in the median function and it worked. Thank you so much!!!!!